# Rails 3 - how to call a method on a nested form object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms, nested-attributes

There is probably a reeeeeally obvious answer to this, but I can't find it, so:

I have a `timesheets` model that has many `time_entries`, added via a nested form:

**timesheets edit.html.erb:**

```
<%= form_for @timesheet do |f| %>
.
.
.
    <%= f.fields_for :time_entries do |builder| %>
            <%= render 'time_entry_fields', :f => builder %>
    <% end %>
```

**time_entry_fields partial**

```
<%= f.text_field :project %>
<%= f.text_field :day1_hours %>
<%= f.text_field :day2_hours %>
<%= f.text_field :day3_hours %>
<%= f.text_field :day4_hours %>
<%= f.text_field :day5_hours %>
<%= f.text_field :day6_hours %>
<%= f.text_field :day7_hours %>
```

I'd like to define a method that shows the sum of all the entered hours - `day1_hours + day2_hours + ...` etc. I tried putting this in the model:

**time_entry.rb**

```
def total_hours
    d1 = day1_hours || 0
    d2 = day2_hours || 0
    d3 = day3_hours || 0
    d4 = day4_hours || 0
    d5 = day5_hours || 0
    d6 = day6_hours || 0
    d7 = day7_hours || 0
    d1 + d2 + d3 + d4 + d5 + d6 + d7
end
```

And it works just fine if I call it on a TimeEntry object in the console:

```
1.9.3p0 :003 > TimeEntry.find(3).total_hours
TimeEntry Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "time_entries".* FROM "time_entries" WHERE "time_entries"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
=> 8
```

But I can't figure out how to call it from within the `time_entry_fields` partial in the form. I would normally be able to define `@time_entry` in the controller so that I could use `@time_entry.total_hours`, but how do you do this for an object in a nested form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`f.object.total_hours` in your partial should be what you want